# Eclipse comment auto-generation

Tags: java, eclipse, comments

For a programming course, I'm required to put comments within each class and method describing the following five things: **Methods**, **fields**, **methods on fields**, **parameters**, and **methods on parameters**. The first three are to be put directly under the class heading, and the last two are specific to each method.

Below is an example of what these comments should look like.

```
class ConsLoString implements ILoString {
    /*
     * Methods:
     * - String convertToString();
     * - String formatString();
     * Fields:
     * - String first;
     * - ILoString rest
     * Methods on fields:
     * - All String methods
     * - All ILoString methods
     */

    String first;
    ILoString rest;

    ...
```

Naturally, it is tedious and redundant to type all these out for every single class and method in a large file. Is there a way to generate these automatically, in Eclipse or otherwise?

I've looked into Eclipse's [Java Editor Template Variables](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-template-variables.htm) but there doesn't seem to be a way to iterate over every method/field in a class within Eclipse's template editor.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Upvote for your question, downvote for this requirement from your course. Push back on them, show them how javadoc is supposed to work. If you use javadoc properly you get the proper summary without having to maintain what your programming course is asking of you. In the "real" world I would be very wary of any company that required such documentation style in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse, go to Window ->Preferences -> Java -> Code style -> Code Templates
On the right hand side, click on Code Style to expand, click on Methods - and in the bottom , check the check box that says : Automatically add comments for new methods and types. You can do the same for Fields also.

I haven't seen anywhere the way you are trying to document java classes. But if it is what you want : See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classMembers.html), and search for `java ClassSpy ClassMember FIELD METHOD` . You can directly take the ClassSpy.java class from that link , compile it and execute the ClassSpy.class  like : `java ClassSpy ConsLoString FIELD METHOD` - It will print the fields, methods as output. Copy the output and use it whatever way you want.

Comment: With this method I am unable to iterate over the list of methods and fields in the given class/interface, which I need to be able to do. I can only get, for example, the enclosing type name or the file name.

Comment: What do you mean by iterate over list of methods, fields? Please make clear what exactly do you want in your post.

Comment: In the example in my post, the comment block shows a list of all of the fields and methods in the class `ConsLoString`. I need to retrieve every field and method (iterate over them) to be able to put them into a comment.

Comment: Edited answer, please take a look.

Comment: Thanks @svasa, this looks like the best way at the moment to add these comments!

Comment: Glad the link helped you.

Answer (score 1):

When you type `/**` right before a class or method definition and then hit return, Eclipse generates some (templated) comments for classes and methods.  You can define the content of the generated comments by going to Window>Preferences>Java>Code Style>Code Templates>Comments.

Comment: With this method I am unable to iterate over the list of methods and fields in the given class/interface, which I need to be able to do. I can only get, for example, the enclosing type name or the file name.

Comment: When you say, "iterate over the list of methods and fields", it sounds like you are trying to "parse" existing "uncommented" class files adding comments appropriate to the parsed information gathered, rather than trying to comply with draconian commenting rules as you write code. The code/comment templating features of Eclipse are meant for "code writing time".  If you are using reflection to "parse" objects and then add comments to the underlying class files, that is also a case where Eclipse comment templating features won't help.

Comment: You're correct, that is exactly what I'm trying to do. It's unfortunate that Eclipse doesn't have that functionality. I'll edit my post to ask for non-Eclipse solutions, because the commenting rules are indeed draconian. :)

Comment: You should be able to define your own "comment templates" as methods of some class that take appropriate parameters and spit out strings that "are" the comments that need to get written wherever your "parsing pointer" currently points.  Then you only need to "write" the comment once in that method and the method will write it however many times you need it, wherever you need it, with whatever parameters you need.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you're suggesting something very similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050458/eclipse-comment-auto-generation/35050516#35050516) answer. This seems to be the way to go, thank you.

Comment: That answer is showing you an existing tool you can use to get (I think) some of the information you need.  But if I understand correctly, you will still need to manually convert the output from ClassSpy into your draconian comment structure within each class file examined by ClassSpy.  I was suggesting you "role your own" so you can automate just about every task you need your code to perform.  The "correct" answer depends on your needs and desires.

Comment: I definitely will have to roll my own method to convert the output from ClassSpy into what I need. Without ClassSpy, however, it'd be much more difficult to write my own comment generator as I'd need to parse the Java somehow.